# PySide2 - Widget above a widget with a shadow effect moves under the second

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, python-3.9

I am writing a virtual keyboard for an app that will be using with touch screen.
If you wanna ask me, why i don't use pyqt virtual keyboard, i'll answer that my keyboard must have some additional buttons and function.

My keyboard is a class, that draws each button when it called(show_keyboard). It has a parent widget that has a slightly transparent background(0.95) and contains the main widget(QVBoxLayout) which contains the layout of each row with character buttons (1,2,3,4,5,6...; q,w,e,r,t,y...; a, s,d,f,g...; z,x,c,v,b,n...) and functional buttons.

Problem is: when i show this keyboard above widget that has a shadow effect, it moves main widget of the keyboard under the widget with shadow.

there is a similar situation in code:

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()

        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        central_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(central_layout)
        central_widget.layout().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.under_widget_with_shadow = QWidget()
        self.under_widget_with_shadow.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray")
        self.under_widget_with_shadow.setFixedSize(QSize(
            QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().size().width(),
            200
        ))
        # shadow effect
        under_widget_shadow_effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        under_widget_shadow_effect.setBlurRadius(15)
        under_widget_shadow_effect.setOffset(-3, -3)
        under_widget_shadow_effect.setColor(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        under_widget_shadow_effect.setEnabled(True)
        self.under_widget_with_shadow.setGraphicsEffect(under_widget_shadow_effect)

        self.under_widget_without_shadow = QWidget()
        self.under_widget_without_shadow.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray")
        self.under_widget_without_shadow.setFixedSize(QSize(
            QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().size().width(),
            200,
        ))

        self.above_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.above_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray")
        above_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.above_widget.setLayout(above_layout)
        self.above_widget.setGeometry(QRect(
            0, QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().size().height() - 500,
            QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().size().width(), 500,
        ))

        for char in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
            row_widget = QWidget()
            row_layout = QHBoxLayout()
            row_widget.setLayout(row_layout)
            for i in range(1, 12):
                btn = QPushButton()
                btn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
                btn.setText(f"{char}{i}")
                row_layout.addWidget(btn)
            above_layout.addWidget(row_widget)

        central_layout.addWidget(self.under_widget_without_shadow)
        central_layout.addWidget(self.under_widget_with_shadow)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.showFullScreen()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: image of the BUG]

When i removed shadow effect from widget it works normally.

Comment: I will tell you only once more: we **NEED** a [mre]. We do ***NOT*** make random guesses.

Comment: (@musicamante Please remember to use your close-votes - if you have any left).

Comment: (@ekhumoro Yes, but I wanted to give one last chance to the OP and reserve the closure vote in case a duplicate was found whenever they finally decided to provide a valid MRE, since I wouldn't be able to do it if I had to retract the closure.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on Linux. What OS are you using? Note, for future reference (and your benefit), use local references to objects that you are going to use multiple times: your code is very confusing to read, as you keep using access functions to get objects you just created; for instance, instead of always using `self.above_widget.layout()`, create it like this `above_layout = QVBoxLayout()`, then just use `above_layout` when calling `setLayout()` or adding widgets to it.

Comment: @musicamante Windows 10

Comment: You say that "It has a parent widget that has a slightly transparent background(0.95)": what are you referring to with the parent widget, the keyboard container or the window? Also, in your code there is no trace of the transparency: is the problem reproducible even with the **exact** code you gave us? What Qt version are you using?

Comment: Parent widget is container for the whole keyboard, qt 5.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding a shadow effect to the keyboard parent frame.

```
self.above_widget.setGraphicsEffect(QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self))
```